# expression blend

Tags: expression-blend

hi
I am using microsoft expression blend2. now i need to work with expression blend3
for this whether we need to uninstall blend2 and again install blend3 or else any alternate solution is there for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blend 2 and Blend 3 can be installed side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

I have Blend 3 and Blend 4 installed side by side on my machine and it works perfectly!